# How can I ensure I always see the end of my JLabel value, even though the display is a fixed length?

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JLabel` with the text "`OutputVariable1=5.34`" in a key=value format. This `JLabel` has a fixed size which can be shorter than the text string it contains.  When this happens, this `JLabel` only shows the text "`OutputVariab...`".  I need to ensure that the `JLabel` always displays the value and that the key name is shortened if the whole string is too long, for example: "`OutputVar...=5.34`". The text string is not constant, so I need to do this programmatically.

How do I do this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

Could you break it up into two Labels, one that contains "OutputVariable" and the other "=5.34" or does the precision of the number vary (i.e. can you have 5.19382 in some cases?)?

If not, use [`FontMetrics.stringWidth()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html#stringWidth%28java.lang.String%29) to figure out how many pixels wide your string will be and, if it's too long, insert "..."  and keep dropping letters at the position where you would like until it fits.